# Failure to reset stdout file descriptor to original value in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, stdout, io-redirection

This is the first time I've ever posted to stackoverflow, so if I'm violating any posting rules or omitting any necessary information, please let me know and I will remedy the issue(s).

So, I am trying to build a shell using C for a homework assignment and I'm running into trouble with input/output redirection. I can redirect some input to a file (by pointing stdout to that file), but when I try to reset stdout back to its original file descriptor value something goes awry. If I try to cat out the file that previously served as my stdout, I get the error cat: myfile: input file is output file, also, if I try to output anything else, it gets written to that file. Here is where I think the problem might be (namely the if statements that execute after the parent resumes execution):

```
int runCommand(char** args,int inputFD,int outputFD)
{
    int status;
    int savedStdOut = dup(STDOUT_FILENO); //save original stdout descriptor
    int savedStdIn = dup(STDIN_FILENO); //save original stdin descriptor

    if(savedStdOut == -1 || savedStdIn == -1)
    {
        perror("Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t spawnpid = fork();

    if(spawnpid == CHILD) //if child
    {
         if(outputFD > 0) //if there is a valid output file open
         {
             dup2(outputFD,STDOUT_FILENO); //point stdout to this file
             close(outputFD);
         }

         if(inputFD > 0) //if there is a valid input file open
         {
             dup2(inputFD,STDIN_FILENO); //point stdin to this file
             close(inputFD);
         }

         execvp(args[0],args);

         perror("Error");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if(spawnpid > CHILD) //if parent
    {
        pid_t exitpid = waitpid(spawnpid,&status,0); //wait for the child to terminate

        if(inputFD > 0) //if an input file was used
        {
            dup2(savedStdIn,STDIN_FILENO); //restore stdin to the original descriptor
            close(savedStdIn);
        }

        if(outputFD > 0) //if an output file was used
        {
             dup2(savedStdOut,STDOUT_FILENO); //restore stdout to the original descriptor
             close(savedStdOut);
        }

        fflush(stdout);
        return WEXITSTATUS(status);
     }
     else
     {
         perror("Error");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
 }
```

It may be important to note that when I trace the values of savedStdOut and savedStdIn, they both continue to increase in value. This makes me think, that maybe I am not closing a particular file(s) since dup() should return the smallest available file descriptor, right? Also, when I call dup() at the beginning of the function, savedStdOut and savedStdIn get assigned the values 3 and 4. This seems to make sense since 0, 1 and 2 are being used by stdin, stdout and stderr, but then shouldn't the next time I call dup() assign 3 and 4 to the relevant variables if I closed everything properly (rather than 5 and 6, then 7 and 8, etc)?

I've been trying to figure this out for about 2 days now and I'm frustrated to the point of not being able to approach it with a level head. Please keep in mind, that I am a student, so I humble myself before the presence of masters. Also, know that appealing for help from you all was not my first choice, and that I spent quite a bit of time trying to solve this problem through research and reason but apparently either my understanding is misguided or I am lacking the proper vocabulary. Any hints, solutions and/or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: There's no point is saving the stdin/stdout file descriptors. The child never restores them, and the parent never redirects them.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for responding. I'm not entirely sure what your comment is suggesting though. Are you saying that my code fails to use the child to restore and the parent to redirect the stdin/stdout file descriptors or that child and parent processes in themselves are unable to do this? If the former, which is what I suspect, then why am I able to redirect the contents of a file into a command (ex: wc < myfile)? This works until I try to something like ls > myfile. All commands after that last one output to myfile and I cant cat out myfile. So mustn't my code be doing some redirection?

Comment: It's the latter, or perhaps the other. I believe that you will see absolutely no difference in the way your code works if you remove the variables `savedStdOut` and `savedStdIn`, and all the code related to those two variables. I also believe that there is additional work that needs to be done in the code that calls `runCommand`. In particular, I'm guessing that you don't properly clean up the `inputFD` and `outputFD`. But I can't say for sure [without seeing that code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That's funny! We figured out my error at the same time. The problem was indeed that I had failed to reset the values of `inputFD` and `outputFD`. This was a total bonehead mistake, but thank you so much for helping me realize it. I will play around with removing `savedStdOut` and `savedStdIn`. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW, the check for a valid fd is NOT `fd > 0`. It's `fd >= 0`. Note that 0 is usually the file descriptor for stdin.